# What are my photography options if I cannot travel or I'm forced to stay at home?

Tags: travel

I used to travel a lot and take photographs at those places. Now borders are closed due to COVID-19 precautions and we'll be probably ordered to stay at home except some special cases.
What are my photography options in this situation?

Comment: how many speedlights or strobes do you have?

Comment: OP: Thanks for all the great answers! I've already upvoted some. Looks like this challenging time is more an opportunity to learn new things than a real limitation in photography.

Answer (score 24):

**First of all: Do everything your government tells you to do. Follow the recommendations. Be rational and don't be careless or selfish!**

In case you can still move freely in your area:

- Explore your neighbourhood. You may be surprised what a nearby forest, park or an old quarry can offer.
- Visit places otherwise occupied by tourists (now probably empty).
- Learn something new. Change your photography genre to a safer one like from street to birds etc.

In case you have to stay at home:

- Study photography. Learn things you can use in the future.
- Catalogue your pictures. Eliminate the mess. Now you have time to do that.
- Post-process your older pictures again. Try creating new, better versions.
- Try studio/abstract photography.

Comment: Well don’t do _everything_. The mayor of Florence told his people to go out and hug Asians to counter the “racist” reaction to Coronavirus. Shortly later they’re on lockdown.

Comment: @vol7ron get woke go choke?

Comment: Wasn’t trying to play politics, just trying to humorously insert “within reason” and suggest we can always use some common sense.

Answer (score 15):

## At home

- studio photography; portraits, food, pets, retail/object photos
- macro photography; dust, bugs, small objects, plants
- time-lapse; light through a window, stars in the sky, a clock
- practical; document items for your home-owner’s/renter’s insurance
- themes: lighting, space, scale, profiling, silhouettes
- technical: improving your computer setup, improving your post

Comment: Light painting!

Answer (score 12):

During night you may do some astrophotography, if light pollution allows you.

Long exposition with lunar or city lights. Sometimes twilight and light pollution may give you beatiful clouds, mountains, cityscapes, etc.

During day, pet photgraphy if you have pets. Internet doesn't have enough cats yet.

Comment: I joined this SE to upvote this answer.

Answer (score 8):

I read a "we" in there.  That implies a partner or family, or at the least a roommate.

That means you have a subject for portraiture or modeling.  A bedsheet or quilt can be pressed into service as a backdrop, floor or desk lamps can work as hot lights, and desk chairs make fine studio stools.  You can, of course, also shoot *in situ*, in places like kitchens, hobby rooms, back yard.  If your partner or roommate is amenable, you could even shoot nude studies.

Photographers have made a whole career shooting subjects you have in your home.  There's no reason to let travel restrictions stop you from learning and enjoying photography.

Comment: Amazing what a little global turmoil will do - it's forcing me & my partner to actually get around to doing those new head- & modelling shots we've been putting off for months ;)

Answer (score 5):

To the individuals who complain there is nothing to photo at home: there is! Most of the photographers spend their whole lives investigating studio photography, all things considered. There is a lot more to do inside a house that, I wager,

Through the act of "home photography" you'll stretch out your interest to new grounds, yet additionally rediscover the photographic open doors around all of you the time, beginning with the dishes and cutlery utilized in your kitchen and going right through to the examples found in a cabinet loaded up with beautiful socks.

Capturing at home doesn't mean your enthusiasm for nature subjects must be left aside. Blossoms are a decent topic to photo home – perhaps you tend a little nursery in pots – and even little creatures, similar to bugs, can be captured in a stopgap studio. The day by day life directly outside your window can be a topic for some undertakings. The experience of shooting at home will instruct you that it doesn't make a difference where you're capturing, it is constantly a test to work with light to get the best outcomes.

These ventures are only the beginning stage of a ceaseless experience for everybody with a camera. I really accept we can, as I use to state, "walk less, photo more", and the idea can and ought to be reached out to individuals that experiences issues moving out from home.

Answer (score 2):

Photography is just about light, objects and your feelings about. As long you have these components, you can do photography :)
Just look now a bit aside of the screen and you may notice something that touches you and try to make photo about. Do not see anything interesting, anything that reflects your feelings? Make or build it.
Regards.

Answer (score 2):

Photography is a lot about story telling. Outdoors this may be a lot easier, but trying to find the stories of daily (quarantined) life may be a good and fun challenge.

Answer (score 2):

A good practice is to take photos within 3 feet of yourself. You only get to take 3 steps after you have taken a photo. You'll find that there are tons of things to take photos of.

Also, highly recommend checking out The Christmas Tree Bucket by Trent Parke for inspiration for shooting at home.

Answer (score 1):

Time to take a photo from the window, streets.. For your personal exhibition about "Time covid-19"

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's Darlene Hildebrandt of [Digital Photo Mentor](https://www.digitalphotomentor.com/) has a 100-photo challenge.

Take 100 photographs of a single item or in a single location in your house.

Sure, some of the photos will be garbage, but creativity is born of limitations.

Answer (score 0):

## In your neighborhood

- If you have a park in your neighborhood, just feel free to go an explore and takes some photographs of it
- Take some photos of small animals you have seen in the park and go home, and do research about it. It is a perfect method to keep yourself busy in this boring and crucial period

## At home

- If you are fond of taking photographs but you are forced to stay at home, do not worry, every single one of us has windows in their home. You could take photos of the scenery outside your window, It will be very beautiful, I promise.
- Participate in art and craft at home and take photographs of them

Comment: Thank you for editing my post